# Call R function in Linux command line

Tags: linux, r, function, command-line

Is there a way to directly call R functions from Linux command line without going into R environment? It doesn't work for me by just running a R file, since I need to specify the parameters of the function every time I run it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A simple built-in is the following BASH commands:

```
export NUM=10
R -q -e "rnorm($NUM)"
```

Answer (score 10):

Yes, there is -- [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) was written for exactly that purpose.

R itself added Rscript shortly thereafter, but as one of the two dudes behind littler I still like it better.

Comment: you beat me by a few second ;) you can also use "`R CMD {$function}`"

Comment: Yes but the indirection and quoting hell becomes awkward real fast once you write more than tiny scripts. But YMMV and choice is a good thing.

Comment: Cheers to two dudes, though I like the other dude's work better (sorry)! =)

Answer (score 1):

If your program is going to work on a single dataset, then simple-r might be the solution:

http://code.google.com/p/simple-r/

It is especially designed for simple statistical analysis as a part of Linux command line.